# Real-Time validation, Good or Bad UX

Tags: forms, validation

I have a signup form where I made a REAL-TIME validation when the user starts typing as you see in the picture.

I don't know if this harms the user experience or no, and also I did not find a resource about this kind of validation.
[image] .

Comment: Personally, I disagree with the answers.  I like being updated after each keystroke.  (But that is just one person's opinion, and not an answer.)

Comment: As an aside, I hope you aren't validating for uniqueness with every keystroke. Please do not do that to yourself. It wouldn't be a problem in the early days but that's the sort of thing that, if your application does that in a lot of places, could cause your data back end to grind to a halt, and the cost of your bandwidth could get out of hand. -Sincerely, a back end guy.

Comment: Test it out with a group of users and get their feedback. I am doing the exactly the same thing you are doing to my forms. I am going to do some user testing to see it is is a problem. The irritation I can see, if the validation keeps appearing and disappearing after every keystroke. That can be annoying.

Comment: Nobody seem to mention input device, keyboard is quite capable, people can type as fast as 100-150 wpm, sometimes meaning your validation can't even keep up, let alone the user gets any productive use out of it. But for phone and touch screen, it is in my opinion that text input is not in a respectable state, even after 20 or so years. The common tactics seem to be to merely avoid any prolonged user input in general, on touch screen devices. However I'm not a ui expert, and following well founded ui rules could be best.

Comment: Also too, if your site doing validation, the browser too, it is getting bad. I see useless and poor validation so much that it seems too many are doing it, and good validation too difficult, that the net validation experience is very poor.

Comment: Maybe for keyboard input, a good rule could be to expect the user can type, and can be left alone except for fields were spelling and spell check are necessary, and then to use basic English dictionary, and refrane from spell check suggestions that are internet lingo and other such things if possible. For security purposes auto log on should be avoided always, for keyboard and touch screen. One solution to auto log on for touch screen is to use a longer decimal pin number. But this has not been used much so there may be reasons?

Comment: Also overly restrictive password rules are not friendly to the user, and I don't believe in my opinion there is much benefit. It seems to me increasing the length of password is enough, and not to use common passwords. Also a message clearly displaying the requirements is better then the user having to exploratory test validation, to find out as I have seen in some rare cases. It seems real issues are security, and touch screen still having ui issues today, all of this are consequences to this.

Comment: I would like to add that for 90 % of internet users, the error message shown is as cryptic as it gets.

Comment: As a side note - do not validate a form when it is still empty just because the browser lost focus. I positively hate it when a form tells me in red that I must type something when I just went somewhere else for a second.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for the answers, after I read all answers and comments, I built by following the rule of validation after keystroke ( onblur). [Demo](https://xux06.csb.app/)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To quote from [nngroup.com](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/errors-forms-design-guidelines/):

> **7. Don’t Validate Fields Before Input is Complete**
> ...
> It can be annoying to see an error message before being given the opportunity to finish typing.

Comment: +1, but "Complete" here is underselling how complex it is to know when someone is finished. Most developers go with validating after each keystroke or on blur for simplicity, but those have issues with over and under validating, respectively. The best case involves waiting a short time after a key press (perhaps inversely proportional to the length of input) but it's complicated if done right and a resource drain if done poorly.

Comment: @NathanRabe The change event works well for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: @NathanRabe Still, on blur is a good alternative for mobile. Android has a button to jump to the next field. So, you either wait some time and randomly show the message, or put it on a blur. I prefer putting on blur first and then validate while the person is typing (if there was an error).

Comment: i find that a good approach is to wait until the field loses focus (blur) to validate for the first time, and then validate per-keystroke after that first validation. that gives the user one full interrupted attempt before being shown an error message, and then live updates while the user makes the needed adjustments to resolve the validation error (since that process is sometimes trial-and-error for the user).

Comment: I prefer debouncing the validations.

Comment: Perhaps validation cost has to be taken into account. If it means a tcp message for every single keystroke, that could be viewed as overboard.

Answer (score 29):

**Validation should not start before input is complete**

When the user starts entering a correct value, no errors should appear while typing. The input is considered to be complete when

- the **input focus is lost** (navigating to another field) or
- the **form is submitted** (e.g. autosubmit when pressing enter) or even
- after **not receiving input for some time** (e.g. 3sec after the last input event).

Showing input errors immediately while typing is very **distracting** ("must have at least 3 characters" when starting to type) and rarely helpful.

**Validation errors should be removed on the fly**

Once the field is validated, and shows some errors, the user wants the error to vanish as soon as the edited value is correct, not when he leaves the field or submits the form (which probably will be disabled anyways as long as there are errors displayed).

This can be achieved by removing all errors from the field when it becomes dirty again (and revalidate it later on submit or focus lost), or automatically revalidating the field every time it is changed.

Answer (score 16):

Rather than continuously display a red validation message when the user has *not* met a field's requirements, a nice alternative is to (1) display a tip that tells the user what is expected, and (2) display a green "requirements met" message when the user has entered a valid value. You can go green as soon as the input is OK.

Comment: This is amazingly sensible advice, and so obvious that I wonder why more people (including myself) don't do it!

Answer (score 12):

**It depends on the type of Input Field.**

[image]

- **For the Email Field:**

You don't wanna be too jumpy. Let the user finish typing the email address.
If the input field turns red with an error-text at the moment the user starts typing, it will annoy the user.

The right approach would be to let the user finish typing and when the user shifts the focus away from that field, validate and show whether it looks good or throw an exception text if there is any.

- **For the Username & Password Field:**

Username and password fields need to be validated pre-submission because they have the strictest input requirements. So clearly show the user what is accepted and what is not in real-time as they start typing.

Link to the Articles:

https://designmodo.com/ux-form-validation/

https://uxmovement.com/forms/why-users-make-more-errors-with-instant-inline-validation/

Comment: I don't agree on showing errors all the time, that gives the wrong message. Better show successful entry. As the source I posted states: "Indicate Successful Entry for Complex Fields".

Comment: @jazZRo There is a difference between error, exception, and suggestions. The OP was asking about validating an input field, not when to show an error

Comment: Ok, the image may show validation messages that are technically no errors. But the messages are red and telling what is wrong with the current input, from a user perspective they are perceived as errors. My point is that any input feels more rewarding when this is brought with a more positive design.

Comment: Is it good to show errors on the right of fields or it eats more spaces ?

Answer (score 3):

Real-time validation works **if** you properly handle incomplete responses.

The example given is bad UI because "reara" is a valid way to start an email address. An example where real-time validation can reject an incomplete response is "reara@@". In that case the real-time validation can reject it without waiting for completion.

In general, you need to be show an error message when there is no additional input which can make the response valid. How hard it is to detect this will vary from case to case. If you have a dictionary, it's fairly easy. With regular expressions, less so.

It of course helps to have good error messages, which are appropriate in the context of incomplete input. "An email address should contain exactly one @ sign" for instance.

If you can't handle incomplete responses, for example because it's always possible to enter a suffix to make a particular field legal, then you should wait for complete input as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: While true for "usual" emails, there is actually the possibility for multiple @-symbols (and oh, so much more) in an email-address (https://stackoverflow.com/q/12355858/3892515)

Comment: @J_F_B_M: Still, `reara@@` is an invalid prefix. Any `@` that's not a separator must be quoted. The error message isn't trying to describe the precise RFC rule, even though that's what the validator should use.

Comment: It seems I [duplicated](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/134426/138705) your answer, somehow I scrolled over this before answering. There are some implementation details in my answer that might prove useful though; if you agree with them and could incorporate them in your answer, we could do away with mine. (There are too many answers to read here already.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about the [problem with live validation](https://adamsilver.io/articles/live-validation-is-problematic/):

In short: it either provides feedback too early and often before the user has had a chance to type their answer OR it provides it too late once the user is finished typing their answer and is focused on the next field answering the next question.

Instead focus on:

- clear and concise label, hint text and error messages
- forgive trivial mistakes
- let the user submit the form when they’re ready

This way users will very rarely see an error message and when they do, it will be when they expect to see one.

Comment: I read your article but In [my form] (https://xux06.csb.app/) I did validate when the user leaves the field empty. Only data.

Comment: Let us know how you get on in user research with it – if you can make sure to test with a diverse set of users.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to validate live. However, such a validation needs to distinguish between two cases:

1. input that can be made valid by adding stuff at the end, and
2. input that can **not** be made valid by adding stuff at the end.

The latter case should pop out the error message instantly, while the former needs to wait until the input is complete.

---

But how can you tell one from another?

That's a bit tricky given current tools, but if you are writing your own regular expression engine (or some other kind of finite state machine for validation) you can achieve it like this:

- if the engine reached the **end of the regexp** (the goal state), there was a match.
- if the engine reached the **end of the string**, there **might** be a match later.
- if the engine couldn't reach either, there's never going to be a match.

The problem is, most programming languages don't give any indication about reaching the end of the string. Also, even though it's a minor change to any existing regexp engine, rolling your own is pretty much certainly out of scope for every user interface design project ever.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer i guess it would be that
if its a login page having 3-4 fields its completely fine to add validation when user clicks submit

Long forms the validation check should trigger when the input is on any other field except the mentioned field.

This is doable in Javascript